# Calculating number of rows that are different

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with several rows in the following format:

```
id | date | position | change_id
1 | 2013-05-14 | 1 | 1
2 | 2013-05-14 | 2 | 2
3 | 2013-05-14 | 2 | 3

4 | 2013-05-15 | 2 | 1 <--- changed from prev day
5 | 2013-05-15 | 1 | 2 <--- changed from prev day
6 | 2013-05-15 | 2 | 3

7 | 2013-05-16 | 2 | 1 <--- not changed from prev day
8 | 2013-05-16 | 1 | 2 <--- not changed from prev day
9 | 2013-05-16 | 2 | 3 <--- not changed from prev day
```

What I'm looking to do is count how many rows have changed in terms of the `position` column between the 2 dates have occurred, i.e. in the example I want to get the number of times that `position` is different between `2013-05-16` and `2013-05-15`. The value would be 0, as the `position` value hasn't changed.

But If I wanted to use the dates `2013-05-15` and `2013-05-14` then the count would be 2, since the position value has changed twice (as shown)

Can this be done in a single query or would i need to do some sort of processing server side?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the relation between each field?

Comment: Each day has 3 rows and the value of `changes` can change daily. So I need to get the total number of rows where the `changes` column are different, i.e if 2 rows have changed (`changes` is different) from the previous day, then the count will be 2 etc etc. So I just need to calculate the number of changes between 2 dates, i.e. how many rows have changed (not the total of `changes` column)

Comment: I think is better if you put a bigger example. Right now but result in `1` so we cant understand all the cases. Reading your comment at most there are 3 rows for dates? so result should be `{0, 1, 2}? Also Isn't clear if  the changes are between same day or different days

Comment: How you compare one day to another? Isnt clear what difference you look. 
In your example all three `changes` are different between those two days for each `change_id`. But you say there are only two? Also there are more dates or just two? A bigger example is required. Also your result doesn't show where is the difference. Looking to your question the answer is two, not `{date, number}`

Comment: I have added some context to the example. You can see there is a `position` column. You can see that the values have changed in the `position` column on 2017-05-15 from the previous day.

Comment: So what is the result you want with this new data?

Comment: I want to get the difference. Based on my example, selecting between `2013-05-14` and `2013-05-15` i should get a value of `2`. Since as you can see in my example above, the `position` field has changed twice since the previous day. I just need the count of all the rows, where the `position` field is different.

Comment: Please edit your question to show me how would look your desire result with that new data.

Comment: I just need a value. So, `changes | 2` would suffice

Comment: You have three dates, how would you have a single result? or you have date as parameter?

Comment: Yes I have 3 dates. I'm looking at seeing the change in the `position` value between 2 dates, i.e. between `2013-05-14` and `2013-05-15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6ebf684a8318f814f5e3a30bc6dfc26f)**

```
SELECT r1.`date`, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN r1.`position` != r2.`position` 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
          END) as daily_changes
FROM `rankings` r1
LEFT JOIN `rankings` r2
  ON r1.`date` = r2.`date` + 1
 AND r1.`change_id` = r2.`change_id`
GROUP BY r1.`date`
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Hi. Using my example above If I have all of the same changes, I get 3. I get the same value if i have all different values for the changes colum

Comment: Example: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=90afd199d2dc0e9dfbab54a54ea1cbf7

Comment: Check this one http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b065bea74c18bd3cafed455ab76f115c   `Day 14 = 0` because doesnt have day before. You have the data without group by so you can debug the source. And you have the final group by with the result I guess you want.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date, MAX(changes) from x GROUP BY date

(or maybe COUNT of changes - not sure what you need given the question)

Comment: I need to know how many of the rows have changed. So in the example above, I have 3 rows for each date. 2 of them have changed (I need this value). I need to calculate how many of them have changed (i have more than 3 rows in my DB)